# Convert array in python

Tags: python, arrays

I am a beginner to python How would I go about doing the below of converting values. Is there a numpy transformation of arrays available.

```
# values = [[0, 1], [2, 3]] to [[0, 2], [1, 3]]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done using numpy's [`transpose()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.transpose.html) function, which can be abbreviated as `T`:

```
In [5]: values = np.array([[0, 1], [2, 3]])

In [6]: values.T
Out[6]: 
array([[0, 2],
       [1, 3]])
```

Comment: +1 , as often happens the best answer has less votes

Answer (score 3):

You don't need numpy, for generic lists of list:

```
>>> a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
>>> b = zip(*a)
>>> print b
[(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)]
```

Comment: Now that is one nice use of `zip`!

Comment: -1 way less efficient on a numpy array  than using .T The OP specifically asked for a numpy solution *Is there a numpy transformation of arrays available.* This also creates  tuples

Comment: Sure BUT the question did not show any snippet of code except a declaration of two normal lists - I inferred that user1741339 thought you NEED to use numpy to transpose and I tried instead to provide a more general answer.

Comment: **Is there a numpy transformation of arrays available.** The whole point of using numpy is efficiency, this is not remotely efficient

Comment: again **I tried instead to provide a more general answer**.

Comment: it is not a general question, it asks about arrays and a numpy method to transpose

Comment: Additionally, while the OP did not specify a Python version, this solution will not work in Python 3, as `zip` generates a zip object. You would need to call `list()` on `b` and again, as @Padraic mentioned, you generate tuples, not a list of lists, which is clearly what OP is looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Why MattDMo's solution is by far the best for a numpy array:

```
In [36]:  values = np.array([range(1000), range(1000)])

In [37]: timeit zip(*values)
10000 loops, best of 3: 120 µs per loop

In [38]: timeit values.T
10000000 loops, best of 3: 196 ns per loop

In [39]: type(values.T)
Out[39]: numpy.ndarray


In [40]: type(zip(*values))
Out[40]: list
```

To get a lists of lists as opposed to tuples, you would need to call map or the equivalent:

```
In [50]: timeit map(list,zip(*values))
1000 loops, best of 3: 360 µs per loop
```

So markedly slower and more importantly you no longer have a numpy array.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use assignment simply.

```
>>> values[0][1], values[1][0] = values[1][0], values[0][1]
>>> values
[[0, 2], [1, 3]]
```